# how to create a json object reading from another json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json like this

```
{
"returnCode" : "200",
"message"     : "",
"Payload":[
  {
   "id" : "A",
   "series" : "Q1",
   "value" : "100",
  },{
   "id" : "A",
   "series" : "Q2",
   "value" : "110",
  },{
   "id" : "B",
   "series" : "Q1",
   "value" : "130",
  },{
   "id" : "B",
   "series" : "Q2",
   "value" : "150",
  }
 ]
}
```

Which i am reading using

```
$.getJSON("file.json",function(data){
     $.each(data.Payload, function(i,v){

     }    
})
```

I can iterate also. but reading from the json i need to create another json object which will used is fusion charts. The json I need to create is like the screenshot i have given[image]

Plz help me to create this dynamically..

Comment: can you add in jsfiddle.net

Comment: So, basically you need to transform one JSON object into another? What are the schemas of the source and target objects?

Comment: source i paste it Andrew. And the target is actually the json which will granted is fusion chart.. see the json http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/MSDV4/                    forget the chart part. just need to create from category.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like
Also your json is different that can not full fill chart all parameters.
you have to include "**seriesname**" viz data value list.Here you have only single list with value.

```
var catagory = [];
var datasetData = [];

//set list
if (response.returnCode == 200) {
    if (response.Payload.length > 0) {
        $(respomse.Payload).each(function (i, item) {
            catagory.push({
                "label": item.series
            });

            datasetData.push({
                "value": item.value
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Your Json object should be

```
var obj = {
    type: 'mscolumn3dlinedy',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '550',
    height: '350',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
        "chart": {
            "caption": "Product-wise Quarterly Revenue vs. Profit %",
            "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart - Last Year",
            "xAxisname": "Quarter",
            "pYAxisName": "Sales",
            "sYAxisName": "Profit %",
            "numberPrefix": "$",
            "sNumberSuffix": "%",
            "sYAxisMaxValue": "25",
            "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500",
            "bgColor": "#ffffff",                
            "showBorder": "0",
            "showCanvasBorder": "0",
            "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
            "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
            "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
            "legendBgAlpha": "0",
            "legendShadow": "0",
            "showHoverEffect":"1",
            "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
            "rotateValues": "1",
            "placeValuesInside": "1",
            "divlineColor": "#999999",
            "divLineIsDashed": "1",
            "divLineDashLen": "1",
            "divLineGapLen": "1",
            "canvasBgColor": "#ffffff",
            "captionFontSize": "14",
            "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
            "subcaptionFontBold": "0"
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "category": catagory
            }
        ],
        "dataset": [
            {
                "seriesname": "Food Products",
                "data": datasetData
            },
            {
                "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
                "data": datasetData
            },
            {
                "seriesname": "Profit %",
                "renderAs": "line",
                "parentYAxis": "S",
                "showValues": "0",
                "data": datasetData
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Apply object to bind chart

```
var revenueChart = new FusionCharts(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, from my understanding, you are trying to format the results of getJSON call. The simplest way to do this would be to organize the `Payload` object in "file.json" the way you need it to be. However, if that's not possible, you have to remember you know the format and properties of the `data` object returned by `getJSON`. Just copy over the ones you need. This code would go instead of your callback `function (data)`.

```
$.getJSON("file.json",function(data){
    // This object will store our properly formatted data, if you need 
    // access to it outside of this function, declare it outside of the callback
    var formatted_data = {
        "categories" : [],
        "dataset": []
    };

    // Used for efficiency to check if for duplicates
    var foundCategories = [];
    var foundSeries = [];

    // Loop over the result
    $.each(data.Payload, function(index, value) {
        // If we have seen this id already, there's nothing more to do
        var id = value["id"];
        if (foundCategories.indexOf(id) === -1) {
            // We have not seen this id before, store it and keep track of it
            foundCategories.push(id);
            formatted_data["categories"].push({ "category": { "label": id } });
        }

        // Check if we have seen this id before
        var series = value["series"];
        var indexOfSeries = foundSeries.indexOf(series);
        if (indexOfSeries === -1) {
            // We have not seen this series before, store it and keep track of it
            foundSeries.push(series);
            formatted_data["dataset"].push({
                "seriesname": series,
                "data": [{ "value": value["value"] }]
            });
        } else {
            // Add the data to the correct existing series
            formatted_data["dataset"][indexOfSeries]["data"].push({ "value":    value["value"] });
        }
    });  
});
```

Once again, it would be much easier if you could get your server to format the JSON for you, so you have to do minimal work on the frontend.

Comment: value["id"] this is not give any value

Comment: I tested it with the JSON you posted, and it gave the right data. I'd need more data to debug this further. What browser are you running this on? What version of jQuery? Can you double check if the object posted is correct?